# How to publish to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I have an mvc application thats built using the repository pattern. My Database resides in the `SmokersTavern.Data` folder. I have published the site to azure. On startup the user must logon thereof will be redirected to the Products table. However I get the following error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what kind of db connection string did you use? have you used a password?

Comment: When publishing it populate the connection string in the wizard (Contains password). However my webconfig doesnt get any new connection string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created the app service + sql and in my visual studio I connected to app service created on Azure. My connection string in my config file was not that of the Azure sql db

Answer (score 2):

It is not allowed to connect to local database when your web app has been published to Azure.

You should create an Azure sql database and connect to it instead. Here's the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase) for you to refer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an Azure resource group deployment project with your Visual Studio web application so that Visual Studio knows where to publish your code. Please take a look at this:

[Creating and deploying Azure resource groups through Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/vs-azure-tools-resource-groups-deployment-projects-create-deploy)

Although, you are using the 'Publish to Azure' feature, I don't see the resource group configuration in the Solution Explorer pane on the right (based upon the screen capture you provided).

Following this document will walk you through the set-up, configuration, and publishing of your web application to Azure.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to have a web app in one resource group, and and a Azure SQL DB database in a separate resource group. From his question, the problem is that he's got a local mdf file sitting in his SmokersTavern.Data folder, and he's trying to read from it. Which is a no-no, I believe.

Comment: By creating the necessary infrastructure in Azure (web tier, database tier, storage account, etc.) he can then publish the entire solution to Azure. This tutorial walks you through entire that process. Another point is that the web app is being deployed under an Azure Cloud Service (very complex) versus under Web Apps (less complex). [Tell me about Azure Cloud Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me#tell-me-about-azure-cloud-services)